# Format Integer in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, string

How to format an integer as 3 digit string? If I give `3` formated string should be `003`

```
printf("%03d\n", 3); // output: 003
```

This doesn't work in Arduino.

Comment: You can use `sprintf` with a `char` array buffer and then pass it to `Serial.print()`.

Comment: Thanks its worked,
'char buff[3];
  sprintf (buff,"%03d",3);
  Serial.print(buff);'

Comment: Rather use `char buff[4]` as you need one byte for the terminating zero that will be added by `sprintf`. If you don't, it may overwrite some value in your stack, leading to hard to understand problems.

Comment: Or you could [setup `printf()` to print through `Serial`](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/480). This way you don't have to allocate room for `sprintf()`, which can be (as you just experienced) error prone.

Comment: BTW, you will need more than 4 chars if the number you print happens to be less than -99 or more than 999. With `buffer[7]` you can safely print any `int`, and with `buffer[12]` you can print any `long`.

Comment: See this if you have a lot of strings and don't want them using up the limited amount of RAM.  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM

Answer (score 3):

The standard C function `printf` print to stdout. Arduino doesn't has a stdout. You can print to Serial, but must prepare/format the string first.

Instead of `printf`, use `snprintf`. It prints to a char array, which you later can use with `Serial.print`, or whatever other function that take a string.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);

  char buffer[4];
  snprintf(buffer,sizeof(buffer), "%03d", 3);
  Serial.println(buffer);
}

void loop() {

}
```

Note: all the comments apply to this answers.